# Sliders and checkbtton in python 3 and tkinter

Tags: python, slider, tkinter

How can I make that when checkbutton is checked that then all Sliders move like one by using python 3 and tkinter?
Thanks for any help! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you will need to save a reference to each of your sliders, which are instances of the Scale widget. Next, you will need to associate a command with the checkbutton (using the `command` attribute) which will be called whenever the checkbutton is checked or unchecked. In that command you can call the `set` method of each slider.

Comment: Can you wrote some simple program for this, because I don't know, beacuse i'm beginner?

Comment: @TheQuiteStupidMan: no, that won't really help you. What you should do is start with a Tkinter tutorial and give yourself a few hours to learn.